# PHP MVC with SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, laravel-4

I know this,

```
http://hostname/params1/params2
```

params1 represent model name and params2 represent action name.

But If i have a model class name like `ReceivedRequest`, how i convert all lowercase in params1(receivedrequest) to class name format? That case often happens during MVC development

Comment: In laravel `param1` will be the controller name and `param2` will the parameter passed to the controller

Comment: in Yii `params1` will be controller name and `params2` will be the action name (assuming default url rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yii you can set the url rules `caseSensitive` option to false (the default is true)

To do that, assuming the default controller/action rule, in your configuration:
    in your configuration:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => array('<controller>/<action>','caseSensitive'=>false),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And note, if you do that, that as a result you should follow the convention that you use lower case when specifying controller mapping (CWebApplication::controllerMap) and action mapping (CController::actions).

Also, the directory names for organizing controllers should be in lower case.

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager